# Error building GraalVM native Image for Micronaut web app

Tags: java, web, native, micronaut, graalvm

I am running into an issue when attempting to make a build or native image on Windows 11. I have also run this using the Ubuntu subsystem, I get the same error as expressed below. I have tested on in my personal project and the basic app found https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java.html I still get the same error :
I am using GraalVM version : graalvm-ce-java17-22.2.0

I ran`./mvnw package -Dpackaging=native-image -X`

I got he following error:

```bash
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.13:build (default-build) on project micronautguide: Execution of /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java17-22.2.0/bin/native-image -cp /mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/C
ompressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target/micronautguide-0.1-shaded.jar --no-fallback -H:Path=/mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/Compressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target -H:Name=micronautguide -H:Class=example.micronaut.Application returned non-zero result -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.13:build (default-build) on project micronautguide: Execution of /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java17-22.2.0/bin
/native-image -cp /mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/Compressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target/micronautguide-0.1-shaded.jar --no-fallback -H:Path=/mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/Compressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target -H:Name=micronautguide -H:Class=example.micronaut.Application returned non-zero result
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Execution of /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java17-22.2.0/bin/native-image -cp /mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/Compressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target/micronautguide-0.1-shaded.jar --no-fallback -H:Path=/mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/Compressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target -H:Name=micronautguide -H:Class=example.micronaut.Application returned non-zero result
    at org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.AbstractNativeMojo.buildImage (AbstractNativeMojo.java:415)
    at org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.NativeBuildMojo.execute (NativeBuildMojo.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

pom XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>example.micronaut</groupId>
  <artifactId>micronautguide</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.3</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
    <release.version>11</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>3.7.3</micronaut.version>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    <exec.mainClass>example.micronaut.Application</exec.mainClass>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-serde-jackson</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration combine.self="override">
          <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
          <classpath>
            <param>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-shaded.jar</param>
          </classpath>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Please help.

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't say much about what's going wrong. Try running the command line from it and see what the real error is

Comment: Hi, when ever i the app ,its working properly that's the tricky so far but to export to a native image its  an issue

Comment: Can you run `/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java17-22.2.0/bin/native-image -cp /mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/Compressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target/micronautguide-0.1-shaded.jar --no-fallback -H:Path=/mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/Compressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target -H:Name=micronautguide -H:Class=example.micronaut.Application` from the command line and tell us what error do you get?

Comment: @saw303 here is by response :  https://pastebin.com/5TkKmvU7

Comment: This might be a missing configuration issue, can you confirm the configs are generated using the native-image-agent? (see here for details: https://www.graalvm.org/22.3/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/AutomaticMetadataCollection/)

Comment: @A.Oubidar well, I am not really sure as to what to look for here, but I would say I am using the framework set up packaging from Micronauts guides. I have looked the GraalVM yes I am using graalvm as GRAALVM_HOME and JAVA_HOME as well , based on the framework I don't see extra config files being generated by the framework .

Comment: here is the another version of the error as well https://pastebin.com/SJC1Z5cP

Comment: I tested with the example of https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java.html with a local installation of GraalVM 22.3.0 and was able to generate the image successfully.

Comment: For the java.lang.IllegalAccessError, a workaround is to export the module during build-time by adding this flag to your build arguments.
`--add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk=ALL-UNNAMED`

Comment: @A.Oubidar thanks , it worked !  i executed ```bash  /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java17-22.2.0/bin/native-image -cp /mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/Compressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target/micronautguide-0.1-shaded.jar --no-fallback -H:Path=/mnt/c/Users/Kinsl/Downloads/Compressed/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java/target -H:Name=micronautguide -H:Class=example.micronaut.Application --add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk=ALL-UNNAMED ```

Comment: So I have applied the same approach to another project that is a bit broader or more complex , Yes i can build the image but seems like some methods are missing or i am getting an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: but the methods exists ! so what could be causing this or what flags should i be passing around